# Doubly linked list using C++ and templates

Tags: c++, linked-list

Working doubly linked list using C++ and templates, I tried to make it by myself. I tried to use head and tail as buffers and make a simple implementation. Please help me understand what I have done wrong, done good and could have done worse.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct node
{
    T value;
    node* prev = nullptr;
    node* next = nullptr;
};


template <typename T>
class LList
{
public:
    LList<T>();
    ~LList();
    T& get(const int& pos) const;
    void insert(const T& value, const int& pos);
    T& remove(const int& pos);
private:
    int n_elements;
    node<T> *head = new node<T>;
    node<T> *tail = new node<T>;

};

template<typename T>
LList<T>::LList()
{
    n_elements = 0;
    head->next = tail;
    tail->prev = head;
}

template<typename T>
LList<T>::~LList()
{
}

template<typename T>
T& LList<T>::get(const int & pos) const
{
    node<T> *temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i <= pos; i++)
        temp = temp->next;
    return temp->value;
}

template<typename T>
void LList<T>::insert(const T & value, const int & pos)
{
    node<T> *temp = new node<T>;
    temp->value = value;
    node<T> *prev = head;
    node<T> *next = head->next;

    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
    {
        prev = prev->next;
        next = next->next;
    }
    prev->next = temp;
    next->prev = temp;
    temp->prev = prev;
    temp->next = next;
    ++n_elements;
}

template<typename T>
T & LList<T>::remove(const int & pos)
{
    node<T> *prev = head;
    node<T> *curr = head->next;
    node<T> *next = curr->next;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
    {
        prev = prev->next;
        curr = curr->next;
        next = next->next;
    }
    prev->next = next;
    next->prev = prev;
    T value = curr->value;
    delete curr;
    --n_elements;
    return value;
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LList.h"

int main()
{
    LList <double> mylist;
    mylist.insert(20, 0);
    mylist.insert(30, 1);
    mylist.insert(40, 2);
    mylist.insert(30, 2);
    mylist.insert(10, 0);
    std::cout << "removing: " << mylist.remove(0) << std::endl;
    mylist.insert(10, 0);
    mylist.insert(10, 0);
    mylist.insert(10, 0);
    std::cout << "removing: " << mylist.remove(3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "removing: " << mylist.remove(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "removing: " << mylist.remove(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << mylist.get(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << mylist.get(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << mylist.get(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << mylist.get(3) << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Does the current code work the way you want it to?

Comment: yes it does, there is no main function but seems obvious.

Comment: If you have tests, it would be preferred you add those to your question.

Comment: ok I added the main function with my little tests, everything seems to work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Includes

`<iostream>` isn't needed by the header, so don't include it there.

## Null pointer

When I try to run the code, I get an attempt to dereference a null pointer at the first `remove(0)`, which crashes the program.  This is because `remove()` returns a *reference* to local variable `value`, which is no longer in scope.  Return it by *value* instead:

```
    T remove(int pos);
 //^^^ not T&
```

## Memory leak

If I add `return 0;` before the crash (or fix the bug), I do see a memory leak:

```
==29576== 168 (24 direct, 144 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 7
==29576==    at 0x4835E2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29576==    by 0x109362: LList<double>::LList() (205728.cpp:27)
==29576==    by 0x10917F: main (205728.cpp:92)
```

I think `~LList()` needs to do more cleanup:

```
template<typename T>
LList<T>::~LList()
{
    for (auto p = head->next;  p != tail;  ) {
        auto next = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = next;
    }
    delete head;
    delete tail;
}
```

## Copy construction

```
205728.cpp:11:7: warning: ‘class LList<double>’ has pointer data members [-Weffc++]
205728.cpp:11:7: warning:   but does not override ‘LList<double>(const LList<double>&)’ [-Weffc++]
205728.cpp:11:7: warning:   or ‘operator=(const LList<double>&)’ [-Weffc++]
```

We need to fix this, and either make the list safely copyable, or totally uncopyable.

## Prefer initialization to assignment

```
LList<T>::LList() : n_elements{0}
                   /^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or just provide a default initializer, as with `prev` and `next`.

## Don't pass primitive types by reference

```
T& get(const int& pos) const;
//             ^^^
```

Built-in types such as `int` are best passed *by value* rather than by const reference (and prefer size type to int for counting objects).  Also, in this case, we probably want to return a reference to `const T` from a const list, and a reference to mutable `T` from a mutable list (*do as the standard containers do*):

```
T const& get(std::size_t pos) const;
T& get(std::size_t pos);
```

## Copying

Prefer to `std::move()` values where possible.  It's not hard to make the list able to accept move-only types:

```
template <typename T>
struct node
{
    T value;
    node* prev;
    node* next;
    node(T value, node *prev = nullptr, node *next = nullptr)
        : value{std::move(value)}, prev{prev}, next{next}
    {}
};
```

```
template<typename T>
void LList<T>::insert(T value, const int pos)
{
    node<T> *temp = new node<T>(std::move(value), prev, next);
```

## Exception safety

Constructing a linked list requires memory to be allocated for `head` and `tail`.  If the first `new` succeeds, but the second fails, we end up leaking memory when the `std::bad_alloc` is thrown.

There's no reason not to make `head` and `tail` be plain sub-objects:

```
private:
    int n_elements = 0;
    node<T> head = { T{}, nullptr, &tail };
    node<T> tail = { T{}, &head, nullptr };
```

(adjust all `head->` to `head.` and other `head` to `&head`; the same for `tail`).

## Remove doesn't need to track `prev` and `next`

Once we've found the target for remove, we can easily access its neighbours:

```
template<typename T>
T LList<T>::remove(const int pos)
{
    node<T> *curr = head.next;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->prev->next = curr->next;
    curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
    T value = std::move(curr->value);
    delete curr;
    --n_elements;
    return value;
}
```

The insert method can be simplified in a similar way.

## The node type needn't be public

Since `node` isn't exposed in the public interface, it can be a private type within `LList`:

```
template <typename T>
class LList
{
    struct node
    {
        T value;
        node* prev;
        node* next;
        node(T value, node *prev = nullptr, node *next = nullptr)
            : value{std::move(value)}, prev{prev}, next{next}
        {}
    };

    // ...

    node head = { T{}, nullptr, &tail };
    node tail = { T{}, &head, nullptr };

};
```

---

## Modified code

I've made some other minor changes to simplify further.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class LList
{
    struct node
    {
        T value;
        node* prev;
        node* next;
        node(T value, node *prev = nullptr, node *next = nullptr)
            : value{std::move(value)}, prev{prev}, next{next}
        {}
        node(const node&) = delete;
        void operator=(const node&) = delete;

        friend void swap(node& a, node& b) {
            using std::swap;
            swap(a.value, b.value);
            swap(a.prev, b.prev);
            swap(a.next, b.next);
        }
    };

public:
    LList() = default;
    LList(const LList<T>&);
    LList(const LList<T>&&);
    LList& operator=(LList<T>);
    ~LList();

    T const& get(std::size_t pos) const;
    T& get(std::size_t pos);

    void insert(T value, std::size_t pos);
    T remove(std::size_t pos);

    template<typename U>
    friend void swap(LList<U>&, LList<U>&);

private:
    std::size_t n_elements = 0;
    node head = { T{}, nullptr, &tail };
    node tail = { T{}, &head, nullptr };
};

template<typename T>
LList<T>::LList(const LList<T>& other)
{
    // work from back to front, so we always insert at position 0
    // (which is the cheapest)
    for (auto i = other.n_elements;  i > 0;  --i) {
        insert(other.get(i-1), 0);
    }
}

template<typename T>
LList<T>::LList(const LList<T>&& other)
{
    swap(*this, other);
}

template<typename T>
LList<T>& LList<T>::operator=(LList<T> other)
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
LList<T>::~LList()
{
    for (auto p = head.next;  p != &tail;  ) {
        auto next = p->next;
        delete p;
        p = next;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void swap(LList<T>& a, LList<T>& b)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(a.head, b.head);
    swap(a.tail, b.tail);
    swap(a.n_elements, b.n_elements);
}


template<typename T>
const T& LList<T>::get(std::size_t pos) const
{
    auto p = head.next;
    while (pos--)
        p = p->next;
    return p->value;
}

template<typename T>
T& LList<T>::get(std::size_t pos)
{
    auto p = head.next;
    while (pos--)
        p = p->next;
    return p->value;
}

template<typename T>
void LList<T>::insert(T value, std::size_t pos)
{
    auto p = &head;
    while (pos--)
        p = p->next;
    auto next = p->next;
    next->prev = p->next = new node(std::move(value), p, next);
    ++n_elements;
}

template<typename T>
T LList<T>::remove(std::size_t pos)
{
    auto p = head.next;
    while (pos--)
        p = p->next;
    p->prev->next = p->next;
    p->next->prev = p->prev;
    auto value = std::move(p->value);
    delete p;
    --n_elements;
    return value;
}
```

From this position, you could consider more advanced topics, such as providing iterators.  Actually, providing full iterator support is quite a lot of work - 12 methods and a pair of classes - but there are some good reviews here that may give you a metaphorical "leg-up".

Or you might consider your own choice of next steps - don't let me constrain you!

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i will work on fixing it.

Comment: i would like to know which compiler you used?because it didn't crash on vs2017, and also didn't warn me about copy constructors. i checked the first answer and understood and changed the things you suggested. I ll check the rest now. i was thinking of implementing merge-sorting, i ll have look about iterators. thanks very much so much help you gave me.

Comment: I used GCC 8.2, with my usual set of warnings: `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds  -Weffc++`.  You may have a compiler with fewer warnings (or perhaps haven't turned them all on).  Merge-sort may well be a better first challenge than getting the iterators right (although once you have iterators, you can use them to do merging of all sorts of container - it's swings and roundabouts, really).

Comment: I did have to find the bug myself, but I shouldn't have had to - I missed the warning for returning a reference to a temporary amongst the other warnings!

Comment: And I used Valgrind 3.13 to examine the memory leak, if that helps...

Comment: yes, thanks. it does help. in what sense merge-sort is better? easier more gradual? or harder? Ill have a look on how to set vs2017 compiler to give more warnings.

Comment: I think that the merge sort might be easier and more fun.  Implementing the iterators can be fairly dull and repetitive IMHO.  Both exercises will teach you plenty, though!